# Handling abnormal Java program exits

Tags: java, database, termination

Suppose I have a Java application that opens a database connection. Normally I would add a connection.close() in a finally block, but this block wouldn't be executed in the case of a kill operation, or any other abnormal termination, would it? Are there any other precautions that I, as a programmer, can make in order to close the connection properly before the application exits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the Runtime.addShutdownHook() method for Java (http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)). It allows you to add a hook that will be called when the virtual machine terminates. You can use it to call a cleanup routine.

That would be for a TERM signal though. A KILL signal will kill the process and not allow it to do any cleanup (because the KILL signal cannot be caught or ignored by the receiving process).

Answer (score 3):

If something external kills your program, there's nothing you can do about it. Obviously they wanted to stop it, so how can you prevent them?

I was going to suggest a [shutdown hook](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)), but the Javadocs state:

> In rare circumstances the virtual machine may *abort*, that is, stop running without shutting down cleanly. This occurs when the virtual machine is terminated externally, for example with the `SIGKILL` signal on Unix or the `TerminateProcess call` on Microsoft Windows. The virtual machine may also abort if a native method goes awry by, for example, corrupting internal data structures or attempting to access nonexistent memory. **If the virtual machine aborts then no guarantee can be made about whether or not any shutdown hooks will be run.**

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 2):

Killing a program will eventually timeout a `TCP` stream from your program to your `[Oracle|SQL Server|MySQL|PostgreSQL]` server.

The server will see it and rollback any pending transactions.

Answer (score 2):

1. You shouldn't need to call connection.close() on application shut-down, since all open files will be closed automatically by the operating system.
2. Also, the Connection's finalize() method should be run before application shut-down automatically (if the shut-down is normal, not ABORTed), and that should close the connection.
3. In any case, you can register [shutdown-hooks](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)), to do any clean-up you require (again, will be run in normal shutdown cases, not ABORTs).

Comment: finalize typically will not run in normal application shutdown. (And Windows 95(!) wont close your sockets after an abnormal exit!)

Answer (score 1):

When you really get killed (`kill -9` on UNIX), you can not do anything against that.

A `finally`-block is the most you can do, see [SO: In Java, is the “finally” block guaranteed to be called (in the main method)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516049/in-java-is-the-finally-block-guaranteed-to-be-called-in-the-main-method) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Some level of abnormal termination is unavoidable. How would you catch the event of the power cable being pulled on the server?