# Java interrupt thread when reading socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, network-programming, interrupted-exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to terminate a thread blocking on socket IO operation instantly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425350/how-to-terminate-a-thread-blocking-on-socket-io-operation-instantly)

I have client run in thread want to read from socket in Java. But while reading, maybe I want to kill the thread. So I `interrupt` it, but does socket's reading methods throw `InterruptedException`? I didn't find.

So, how can I nicely ask thread to die while it's blocking on reading socket?

Thanks

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569226/serversocket-thread-close-socket-failed-howto-stop-thread-correctly-java

Comment: [Check this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54495038/read-from-bufferedreader-for-a-specific-duration/54496477#54496477), it works for **Reader** and **InputStream**

Answer (score 2):

It has been answered [How to terminate a thread blocking on socket IO operation instantly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425350/how-to-terminate-a-thread-blocking-on-socket-io-operation-instantly)

Basically, when you `close()` the socket, all the associated streams will close, causing all the blocked operations to be unblocked.

Or you can call `Thread.interrupt()` and it will interrupt the blocking operation causing it to throw the `InterruptedException`.

Comment: Can I close socket from one thread while another blockin on its "read"?

Comment: I checked this with Java 8 and at least there *no* InterruptedException is thrown. The read method just returns (with -1) and Thread.interrupted() flag is set.

Answer (score 2):

The NIO Channels have [InterruptableChannel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/InterruptibleChannel.html)s which will be interrupted on blocking operations. You can use NIO with blocking operations so they work much the same as Java IO i.e. you don't have to redevelop your application to use Selectors/Dispatchers etc.