# Read from BufferedReader for a specific Duration

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedreader

So, I'm reading from a BufferedReader. Everything goes fine, until I add one condition. I need to read from BufferedReader for a specific duration of time.

This is what I'm doing right now.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null
                    && System.currentTimeMillis() - start < maxReadTime.toMillis()) { 
    // doingSomethingHere()
}
```

The problem: InputStream is active even after the time has elapsed. 
For example - maxReadTime is 30 seconds. the input keeps coming in 20 seconds. For the next 12 seconds, there's no activity. Now when the next input arrives, the stream is open and closes only after it has read the input. However, I don't process this input because while loop terminates.

What I expected or what I need: is Stream will close at 30 seconds. That is when the input arrives at 32nd second, the stream is closed and not listening to any input.

I know vaguely about ExecutorService. I'm not sure if that's the correct way to go.

Comment: You need to test the time first. Otherwise you ar still blocking in `readLine()` when the timer elapses. If reading from a  socket you should set a read timeout on the socket instead of all this.

Comment: The InputStream can be from anything. So not specifically sockets. So should I run another while loop before the readLine()?

Answer (score 1):

Just put your timer condition before reading from stream

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    boolean active = System.currentTimeMillis() - start < maxReadTime.toMillis();
    if (!active) {
        br.close();
    }         
    // doingSomethingHere()
}
```

In this case if the first condition is `false` (time is expired), the second won't be executed at all

Comment: So, the thing is InputStream is still active. It only breaks when I input something to it. I was looking into something where the InputStream will close when the Duration has elapsed.

Comment: Still doesn't work man. I can still take input even when the duration has elapsed.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to check if buffer is ready before call `readLine()` by calling method `ready()`, for `InputStream` check `available()` method which returns how may bytes you can read without block.

Here an example

```
import java.io.*;
import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final InputStream in =  System.in; //new FileInputStream(new File("/tmp/x"));
        final String out = readInput(in, Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        System.out.printf("m=main, status=complete, out=%s%n", out);
    }

    public static String readInput(InputStream in, Duration duration) {
        final long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            String line = null;
            while (true){
                if(Duration.ofMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp).compareTo(duration) >=0 ){
                    System.out.println("m=readInput, status=timeout");
                    break;
                }
                if(!reader.ready()){
                    System.out.println("m=readInput, status=not ready");
                    sleep(1000);
                    continue;
                }
                line = reader.readLine();
                if(line == null){
                    System.out.println("m=readInput, status=null line");
                    break;
                }
                out.append(line);
                out.append('\n');
                System.out.printf("m=readInput status=read, line=%s%n" , line);
            }
            return out.toString();
        } catch (IOException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            System.out.println("m=readInput, status=complete");
        }
    }

    static void sleep(int millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }

}
```

If you wanna do this in background you can follow this example

```
package com.mageddo;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        final InputStream in =  System.in; //new FileInputStream(new File("/tmp/x"));
        final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        final Future<String> promise = executor.submit(() -> readInput(in, out));
        try {
            final String result = promise.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.printf("m=main, status=success, result=%s%n", result);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            System.out.println("m=main, status=timeout");
            in.close();
            promise.cancel(true);
            System.out.println("Failed output: " + promise.get());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            executor.shutdown();
            System.out.println("m=main, status=shutdown, out=" + out);
        }
    }

    public static String readInput(InputStream in, StringBuilder out) {
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        try {
            String line = null;
            while (true){
                if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                    System.out.println("m=readInput status=interrupt signal");
                    break;
                }
                if(!reader.ready()){
                    System.out.println("m=readInput, status=not ready");
                    sleep(1000);
                    continue;
                }
                line = reader.readLine();
                if(line == null){
                    System.out.println("m=readInput, status=null line");
                    break;
                }
                out.append(line);
                out.append('\n');
                System.out.printf("m=readInput status=read, line=%s%n" , line);
            }
            return out.toString();
        } catch (IOException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            System.out.println("m=readInput, status=complete");
        }
    }

    static void sleep(int millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

}
```

[See the reference](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue153.html)

Comment: if InputStream is annotated with @WIllNotClose, would this still work?

Comment: Sure, because the solution it's not related to `close()` method but with `ready()`, give it  a try

Comment: What does promise.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) do?

Comment: It wait for 5 seconds then gave up if the times goes out, if it happen an TimeoutException will be thrown then the catch will set the thread as interrupted then the readInput method will stop read from inputstream

Comment: So where am I checking the duration then? In the readInput method?