# Safe try/catch java

Tags: java, try-catch

```java
try {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(file,FILENAME)));
        String readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
        //do stuff

    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw e; 
    } finally {
        if (bufferedReader!=null)
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

will the bufferedReader closing be invoked in any case in this code?

Comment: Did you try to debug it?

Comment: @Reimeus yes, but i cant think of every possible test case so i tried to get an answer from someone with better experience...

Comment: @OfekRon you could easily supply a file that doesn't exists...

Comment: it's closed but maybe still not what you want: http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.de/2008/10/java-how-not-to-make-mess-of-stream.html (mostly relevant for outputstreams)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes it invokes in any case( if it is not null in you case).According to java [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)

> The finally block always executes when the try block exits. This ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected exception occurs. But finally is useful for more than just exception handling — it allows the programmer to avoid having cleanup code accidentally bypassed by a return, continue, or break. Putting cleanup code in a finally block is always a good practice, even when no exceptions are anticipated.

If you are using Java7 then I strongly recommond to use [try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).Then you do not require to write the *finally* block in your code.

try-with-resouce example

```
     try (BufferedReader  bufferedReader = 
             new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(file,FILENAME)));) {
              String readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
              //do stuff   
      } catch(Exception e) {
           throw e; 
     }
```

**Note:**
*finally* block won't execute in only one case.  That is when JVM shutdown(generally with `System.exit()` statement or when the JVM process is killed externally).  In all other cases the *finally* is guaranteed to execute

Comment: One proviso that is important to note - if the JVM exits before the finally block executes, then it won't execute.  ie, `System.exit()`

Comment: @stormeHawke Yes you are right.That is the only one case finally block won't excutes.But it means JVM shutdown,when JVM shutdown the opened resources will be closed.am I correct..?

Comment: @Prabhaker maybe it will be, for the sake of completion, good the add the comment above to the answer...

Comment: @Prabhaker - In this case, most likely, though that is an OS dependent assumption.  IE, the OS has to recognize that the JVM has shut down and release any file locks.  Not all OSes do this (Windows is fairly notorious for not always catching this).  Additionally, any other "cleanup" operations that might be intended to be persistent in some fashion won't get executed.  It's probably a rare case where this will cause a problem, but it's still important to know

Comment: @stormeHawke I updated the answer to reflect your suggestion.Thank you very much for improving my answer.

Comment: @anakata I updated the answer to reflect your suggestion.Thank you very much for improving my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally is always executed, even if the exception is thrown or not. So it will execute the `bufferedReader.close();` when `bufferedReader` is not null

Comment: Note that if something calls System.exit(), or if the process is terminated externally before the block is reached, the finally block will NOT execute.

Answer (score 0):

finally in a try/catch block means that it will happen no matter what.
Also, the exception would be better stated as IOException.
There is really no reason to have a catch block throw an exception in this situation.

Note: It is true that invoking System.exit() will terminate your could as soon as it is encountered and will result in the application being terminated by the JVM (Java Virtual Machine).

Comment: Note that if something calls System.exit(), or if the process is terminated externally before the block is reached, the finally block will NOT execute.

Comment: @StormeHawke Answer above has been changed to reflect your comment as this is true.

Answer (score 0):

I would refer you to this question:

[In Java, is the "finally" block guaranteed to be called (in the main method)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516049/in-java-is-the-finally-block-guaranteed-to-be-called-in-the-main-method)

Basically, the finally block will always get run, with one exception: If the JVM exits before the finally block executes.

As to whether the bufferedReader executing - as written, so long as it's not null, yes, with the above noted exception

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this code will close bufferedReader in any situation. But in general the code looks like a mess. Java 7 try-with-resources is the best solution of closing resources

```
try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(file,FILENAME))) {
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Try-with-resources is a great thing.  Note that if something calls System.exit(), or if the process is terminated externally before the block is reached, the finally block will NOT execute.