# Java Finally Not Called when using RequestDispatcher

Tags: java, servlets, try-catch-finally

We have a Java servlet acting as dispatcher for a web app. For each request a database connection is created and then committed / rolled back at the end of the request depending on whether the action was successful or not. It looks something like:

```
public class WebDispatcher extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
                                  HttpServletResponse response)
                                  throws ServletException, IOException {

        Connection conn = null;

        try {

           // Create connection

        } catch(.....) { 

        } finally {

          // Commit / Rollback connection

        }

    }

}
```

The problem occurs when there is an exception. For example if they don't have access to a certain action the dispatcher has to redirect them. It does this by using a request dispatcher.

```
} catch(RoleAuthorizationException rae) {

    request.getRequestDispatcher(.....).forward(request, response);

}
```

I had assumed that 'finally' would be called but it doesn't seem to be in this case. With each exception we end up losing a connection in the pool. As a workaround we are closing the connection with each exception but why isn't finally being called?

Comment: Perhaps some of these answers and comments will give you an idea? [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/does-finally-always-execute-in-java)

Comment: i am guessing your example code is not representative. esp since "closing the connection with each exception" works. i think your connection is held by an instance variable or threadlocal, and it gets overwritten when the forwarded request gets processed, leaving the original connection hanging out to dry.

Comment: I think you're absolutely right, just didn't see it. The connection is put into the request and passed into the next action which is usually a call to the dispatcher again. The dispatcher never bothers to check and see if there is already a connection in the request and creates a new one overriding the existing connection and leaving it as you said hanging out to dry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally [is always called](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) (oracle docs):

> The finally block always executes when the try block exits.

Check if there is an exception being thrown in the finally block (before the connection is closed).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/516060/154066).